# Refactoring Methods

Tags: ruby

I have built a Tic Tac Toe game and want to refactor two similar methods into one.

```
def computer_offense(brd, square='')
  WINNING_LINES.each do |line|
    square = find_at_risk_square(line, brd, COMPUTER_MARKERR)
    break if square
  end
  square
end

def computer_defense(brd, square)
  WINNING_LINES.each do |line|
    square = find_at_risk_square(line, brd, PLAYER_MARKER)
    break if square
  end
  square
end
```

Comment: this question should be moved to codereview network

Comment: Thanks llya, I will do that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you can refactor like this:

```
def computer_offense_or_defense(brd, square='', offense=true)
  WINNING_LINES.each do |line|
    square = find_at_risk_square(line, brd, offense ? COMPUTER_MARKERR : PLAYER_MARKER)
    break if square
  end
  square
end
```

So where previously called computer_offense now you can call `computer_offense_or_defense(brd, square,true)`
and for computer_defense you can call

```
computer_offense_or_defense(brd, square,false)
```

Comment: Thanks.  It seems so simple, but I wasn't able to get there.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor it like this

```
def computer_offense(brd, square='')
  get_square(brd, square, COMPUTER_MARKERR)
end

def computer_defense(brd, square)
  get_square(brd, square, PLAYER_MARKER)
end

def get_square(brd, square, marker)
  WINNING_LINES.each do |line|
    break if square = find_at_risk_square(line, brd, marker)
  end
  square
end
```